# awk to print all numbers between starting number in column1 and ending number in column2

Tags: awk

I have data in 2 columns in below format

```
92312401               92312403
92312417               92312418
92345810               92345814
```

and want output to print all numbers starting from value in `$1` and end at value in `$2` in awk.  e.g. output should be like.

```
92312401
92312402
92312403
92312417
92312418
92345810
92345811
92345812
92345813
92345814
```

Can someone please help that how it can be done in linux/unix environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply:

```
awk '{ for(i = $1; i <= $2; ++i) print i }' filename
```